# How to slide two elements, side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

Here's the code of the actual effect:

```js
function nextStepTransition() {
 $("#step1").velocity("transition.slideLeftBigOut", 2000);
 $("#step2").velocity("transition.slideRightBigIn", 2000);
}
```

```css
#step2 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.js"></script>

<div id="step1">
  <p>I'm step number one!</p>
  <button onClick="nextStepTransition()">click me to go to the next step</button>
  </div>
<div id="step2"> 
  <p>I'm step number two</p>
</div>
```

We wish that, step2, when coming in, should NOT stay below step1, but side by side.

Any push please?

Fairly new to velocity.js and not that good in js.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps changing the postion atribute of `#step1` and `#step2` to `absolute` may do the trick? Need to try this later.

Comment: When questions are to simple, people tend to downvote them. Just because they are simple, doesn't mean the  solution is easily answered for some of us.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, although there will be a point when they are overlapping in position (as you can see from the example).

```js
function nextStepTransition() {
  $("#step1").velocity("transition.slideLeftBigOut", 2000);
  $("#step2").velocity("transition.slideRightBigIn", 2000);
}
```

```css
#step1, #step2 {
  position:absolute;
}

#step2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.js"></script>

<div id="step1">
  <p>I'm step number one!</p>
  <button onClick="nextStepTransition()">click me to go to the next step</button>
</div>
<div id="step2"> 
  <p>I'm step number two</p>
</div>
```

If you do this though, you need to make sure that the position of the parent element is set correctly, or both elements may be thrown to the top of the page (or next element that has position:absolute or position:relative). You could also float them both left, although because velocity isn't changing the width of the #step1 element while it's animating, they'll be a snap like effect at the end of the animation for the first element when it finally does display none on the first element.

I'm not familiar with velocity, but there are number of other ways to do this with just jQuery, or even maybe even better, just css (with the exception of the click handler).

jQuery example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#theButton").on('click', function(){
    $("#step1").animate({
      marginLeft: "-200px",
      opacity: 0
    }, 2000, function(){
      $(this).hide()
    });
    $("#step2").show().animate({
      opacity: 1,
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
}
#step1, #step2 {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
#step2 {
  opacity:0;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="step1">
    <p>I'm step number one!</p>
    <button id="theButton">click me to go to the next step</button>
    </div>
  <div id="step2"> 
    <p>I'm step number two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#theButton").on('click', function(){
    $("#step1").addClass("fadeAway");
    $("#step2").addClass("fadeIn");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
}
#step1, #step2 {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
#step2 {
  opacity:0;
  display:none;
}
#step1.fadeAway {
  animation: moveAndFadeOut 2s forwards;
}
#step2.fadeIn { /*need to add "#step2" here to override styles above*/
  display:block;
  animation: fadeIn 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes moveAndFadeOut {
  0% {margin-left:0px; opacity:1;}
  100% {margin-left:-200px; opacity:0; display:none;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="step1">
    <p>I'm step number one!</p>
    <button id="theButton">click me to go to the next step</button>
    </div>
  <div id="step2"> 
    <p>I'm step number two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, for the CSS method above, I didn't add browser prefixes in simply because I was just trying to show how to do it...if you're going to use that method, make sure to add in the necessary browser prefixes for the keyframes and animation stuff.

Comment: Tky. Due to performance and browser support issues, I decided to not use jquery, nor css for this. I'm glad with the position, I will have a container with the default set to relative, just to see what I do get. ty!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, however I'm curious why you're not using jQuery to animate this when you're already using it for selectors anyway? If jQuery performance is an issue, I'd recommend getting rid of it altogether and just use vanilla javascript and go with velocity (if the performance is indeed better).

Comment: Mike S. you can perfectly use Velocity.js with jQuery as they state on velocity.js docs, because Velocity does not replace all jquery. The only thing it does, as far as I was able to read, is that it replaces the animation() part of jquery. And that's the reason why so many people are using it I guess.